# In metric spaces, is a function uniformly continuous iff $\delta$ depends on $\varepsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Most book examples end with an expression for $\delta$ that depends on $\varepsilon$ when proving uniform continuity. What I am wondering is whether a function can be uniformly continuous as long as the distance between any two elements of the domain of the metric space is within some number that does not depend on $\varepsilon$ or the where we "fix" the domain.

Comment: The question is not whether delta depends on epsilon (it always does, except for constant functions), but whether delta depends on epsilon AND ON THE POINT x, or only on epsilon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exist bounded, non uniformly continuous functions, so the answer is no. One example of such a function is $f(x)=\cos(x^2)$, for $x\in\mathbb R$. Then, for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$, you have that $|\cos(x^2)-\cos(y^2)|\leq 2$, but $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I see. So, delta has to depend on epsilon then.

Comment: What is crucial is that the definition has to hold for all $\varepsilon$. There is no need for $\delta$ to depend on $\epsilon$, though.

Comment: What would be one example of such case?

Comment: You could consider a constant function.